# Custom angular app for custom spartacus storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Our requirement is to use multiple angular apps, 1 for ootb spartacus storefronts and 1 for custom site. By following [this github link](https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-commerce-sample-setup/tree/2005-spartacus/js-storefront) we had created new app at below location.  and updated manifest.json, to build 2 angular apps in CCV2. but the deployment was failed. Can you please suggest steps to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: What errors / stacktrace did you see in CCV2?

Comment: Generating Nginx config
No JS Applications configuration in environment properties, generating default config
Generating configuration for vhost=spartacusstore, jsapp=spartacusstore, server_name=~^.*spartacusstore.*$, extensions=bmp|ejs|jpeg|pdf|ps|ttf|class|eot|jpg|pict|svg|webp|css|eps|js|pls|svgz|woff|csv|gif|mid|png|swf|woff2|doc|ico|midi|ppt|tif|xls|docx|jar|otf|pptx|tiff|xlsx
Injecting backend API
Backend API = https://url
Generating /opt/jsapps/daspartacusstore/index.html, backend_api=https://url
cp: can't stat '/opt/jsapps/daspartacusstore/index.html': No such file or directory